# How to extract seperate x, y, z coordinates from an unreal vector in python?

Tags: python, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I am using python script in unreal engine 5.1. I am trying to extract the x, y, z pairs separately from an unreal vector in python.

I tried all the syntax like:

```
vector = unreal.vector() #defined as a vector
vector[0]
vector(0)
vector{0}
```

but non of these are working. Can someone tell me how to do it?

This is the python script I am using.

```
import unreal
import torch

Assets = unreal.Actor(name='cylinder_bp').get_actor_location()

print(Assets)
#print(torch.tensor(Assets))
```

error:

```
LogPython: Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
LogPython: Error:   File "C:/Devanshu/RL/actors.py", line 6, in <module>
LogPython: Error:     for a in Assets:
LogPython: Error: TypeError: 'Vector' object is not iterable
LogPython: C:\Devanshu\RL\actors.py
LogPython: <Struct 'Vector' (0x000001C98DB7F9C0) {x: 0.000000, y: 0.000000, z: 0.000000}>
LogPython: C:\Devanshu\RL\actors.py
LogPython: Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
LogPython: Error:   File "C:/Devanshu/RL/actors.py", line 6, in <module>
LogPython: Error:     print(Assets(0))
LogPython: Error: TypeError: 'Vector' object is not callable
LogPython: C:\Devanshu\RL\actors.py
LogPython: Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
LogPython: Error:   File "C:/Devanshu/RL/actors.py", line 6, in <module>
LogPython: Error:     print(Assets[0])
LogPython: Error: TypeError: 'Vector' object is not subscriptable
```

Also, Can somebody tell me how to get location of the particular actor? In my case there are two actors, `cart` and `cylinder_bp`.

I tried this syntax `"Assets = unreal.Actor(name='cylinder_bp').get_actor_location()"`
but this is not working.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: I have changed the images with the text code.

Thanks to let me know.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/PythonAPI/class/Vector.html), you'd access the `x`, `y`, and `z` properties of the `unreal.Vector` object. Have you not even read the documentation or tried that yet?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used this library so had to look up the solution myself. I googled "python unreal vector" to find [the documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/PythonAPI/class/Vector.html). Reading the docs is much often a better way to find a solution than just guessing.

You can see there is a section called "Editor Properties" that lists `x`, `y`, and `z`. This means you can do `vector.x`, `vector.y`, and `vector.z` to get these values.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is not going to print data from actors correctly as I mentioned on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75701541/176769).

What you are trying to accomplish can be done like this:

```
# Enable these plugins in UE4Editor:
#   - Python Editor Script Plugin
#   - Editor Scripting Utilities
#
import unreal

actorsList = unreal.EditorLevelLibrary.get_all_level_actors()
for actor in actorsList:
    actorLabel = actor.get_actor_label()
    actorPos = actor.get_actor_location()
    if (actorLabel == 'cylinder_bp'):
        print('actorPos.x= %f actorPos.y= %f actorPos.z= %f' % (actorPos.x, actorPos.y, actorPos.z))
```