# How to get a particular actor location with python in unreal engine?

Tags: python, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I am using python script in unreal engine 5.1. I am trying to extract the location x, y, z coordinates of a particular actor from python in Unreal Engine.

I tried this code to extract the location but it is showing the {0, 0, 0) result. In this code **cylinder_bp** is the name of actor in UE.

```
import unreal
import torch

Assets = unreal.Actor(name='cylinder_bp').get_actor_location()

print(Assets)
```

Output: (The actual location of the cylinder is -10, -123, 118)

```
LogPython: C:\Devanshu\RL\actors.py
LogPython: <Struct 'Vector' (0x000001C98DB5C1A0) {x: 0.000000, y: 0.000000, z: 0.000000}>
```

I saw the documentation. I think I am doing it in the right way. I dont know what is the problem?
Please let me know.

https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/PythonAPI/class/Actor.html#unreal.Actor

Comment: FTR, the reason it did this is you are creating a new actor of that name, which defaults to location (0, 0, 0) and then are immediately calling the method to look up its location.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works correctly when trying to access actor's information from the UE4Editor Viewport:

```
# Enable these plugins in UE4Editor:
#   - Python Editor Script Plugin
#   - Editor Scripting Utilities
#
import unreal

actorsList = unreal.EditorLevelLibrary.get_all_level_actors()
for actor in actorsList:
    actorLabel = actor.get_actor_label()
    actorPos = actor.get_actor_location()
    if (actorLabel == 'cylinder_bp'):
        print('actorLabel= %s actorPos=%s' % (actorLabel, actorPos))
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick addition for those wandering around:
From my understanding,

```
Assets = unreal.Actor(name='cylinder_bp').get_actor_location()
```

Basically creates a new actor named cylinder_bp, then get the actor location of the new actor -> 0,0,0